# MySQL variable is not working in case expression as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is a part of my query where variable `@days` is not working in `CASE` expression while it was working well in previous version of MariaDB. It works if I put the `DATEDIFF('2018-02-26', '2018-02-22')` in place of `@days` in the expression part of the case but why it is not working if I assign it to a variable?

```
SELECT @is_base := 'Yes', @days := DATEDIFF('2018-02-26', '2018-02-22') days,
(CASE 
  WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days < 7) THEN r.nightly * @days
  WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days >= 7 AND @days < 28) THEN (r.weekly / 7) * @days
  WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days >= 28) THEN (r.monthly / 28) * @days
  ELSE u.base_rate_nightly * @days
END) AS total_price
```

**Update** Following is the complete query.

```
`SELECT `u`.`ID`, `u`.`destination`, `u`.`unit_name`, `u`.`base_rate_nightly`, `u`.`lat`, `u`.`lng`, `u`.`number_of_bedrooms`, `u`.`max_guests`, `r`.`ID` as `rate_id`, `r`.`nightly`, `r`.`weekly`, `r`.`monthly`, `i`.`filename`, `t`.`name` as `unit_type`, @days := DATEDIFF('2018-02-26', '2018-02-22') days, `u`.`base_rate_nightly` as `total_price`, 'Yes' is_base, @is_base := if(('2018-02-22' <= r.enddate) and ('2018-02-26' >= r.startdate) or ('2018-02-22' <= r.enddate)  and  (r.startdate <= '2018-02-26'), 'No', 'Yes') as is_base, CASE 
                        WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days < 7) THEN r.nightly * @days
                        WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days >= 7 AND @days < 28) THEN (r.weekly / 7) * @days
                        WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days >= 28) THEN (r.monthly / 28) * @days
                        ELSE u.base_rate_nightly * @days
                    END AS total_price
FROM `vs_units` `u`
LEFT JOIN `vs_unit_images` `i` ON `u`.`ID` = `i`.`ID_unit`
LEFT JOIN `vs_unit_rates` `r` ON `u`.`ID` = `r`.`ID_unit` AND (('2018-02-22' <= r.enddate) and ('2018-02-26' >= r.startdate) or ('2018-02-22' <= r.enddate)  and (`r`.`startdate` <= '2018-02-26'))
LEFT JOIN `vs_unit_types_readonly` `t` ON `t`.`ID` = `u`.`ID_unit_type`
WHERE `u`.`max_guests` >= '1'
AND   (
`u`.`ID` NOT IN(SELECT DISTINCT ID_unit from vs_calendar WHERE ('2018-02-22' <= enddate) and ('2018-02-26' >= `startdate`) or ('2018-02-22' <= `enddate`)  and  (startdate <= '2018-02-26'))
 )
GROUP BY `u`.`ID`
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the `CASE` expression.  It is the use of variables in multiple columns.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of assignment of variables in expressions.

In your case, you have a simple solution.  Just move the logic to the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT @days as days,
       (CASE WHEN @is_base = 'No' AND @days < 7 THEN r.nightly * @days
             WHEN @is_base = 'No' AND @days >= 7 AND @days < 28 THEN (r.weekly / 7) * @days
             WHEN @is_base = 'No' AND @days >= 28 THEN (r.monthly / 28) * @days
             ELSE u.base_rate_nightly * @days
        END) AS total_price
FROM (SELECT @is_base := 'Yes',
             @days := DATEDIFF('2018-02-26', '2018-02-22')
     ) params;
```

The `FROM` clause is guaranteed to be evaluated before the `SELECT`.

I should note that with this structure, there is no need to use variables:

```
SELECT days,
       (CASE WHEN is_base = 'No' AND days < 7 THEN r.nightly * days
             WHEN is_base = 'No' AND days >= 7 AND days < 28 THEN (r.weekly / 7) * days
             WHEN is_base = 'No' AND days >= 28 THEN (r.monthly / 28) * days
             ELSE u.base_rate_nightly * days
        END) AS total_price
FROM (SELECT 'Yes' as is_base,
             DATEDIFF('2018-02-26', '2018-02-22') as days
     ) params;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning values to variables, and reading them inside the same statement. This is not recommended. [From the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement.

Place the [`SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) statements *before* your query:

```
SET @is_base := 'Yes';
SET @days := DATEDIFF('2018-02-26', '2018-02-22');

SELECT
    @is_base,
    @days AS days,
    CASE
        WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days < 7) THEN r.nightly * @days
        WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days >= 7 AND @days < 28) THEN (r.weekly / 7) * @days
        WHEN (@is_base = 'No' AND @days >= 28) THEN (r.monthly / 28) * @days
        ELSE u.base_rate_nightly * @days
    END AS total_price
FROM r
```

As for your revised query, I think you can simply place all variables inside a derived table and join remaining tables with it:

```
FROM `vs_units` `u`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN ('2018-02-22' <= r.enddate) and ('2018-02-26' >= r.startdate) or ('2018-02-22' <= r.enddate)  and  (r.startdate <= '2018-02-26') THEN 'No'
            ELSE 'Yes'
        END as is_base,
        DATEDIFF('2018-02-26', '2018-02-22') AS days
) params
LEFT JOIN `vs_unit_images` `i` ON `u`.`ID` = `i`.`ID_unit`
LEFT JOIN `vs_unit_rates` `r` ON `u`.`ID` = `r`.`ID_unit` AND (('2018-02-22' <= r.enddate) and ('2018-02-26' >= r.startdate) or ('2018-02-22' <= r.enddate)  and (`r`.`startdate` <= '2018-02-26'))
LEFT JOIN `vs_unit_types_readonly` `t` ON `t`.`ID` = `u`.`ID_unit_type`
```

You can then replace all @days and @is_base with params.days and params.is_base.

PS: I think this:

```
('2018-02-22' <= enddate) and ('2018-02-26' >= startdate) or ('2018-02-22' <= enddate) and (startdate <= '2018-02-26')
```

Could be written as:

```
('2018-02-22' <= enddate) and ('2018-02-26' >= startdate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :-), according to @Gordon "MySQL does not guarantee the order of assignment of variables in expressions", so I think it will not work and another problem is that I am using Codeigniter's query builder so it is a bit tricky to use set things, I already tried that but I failed.

Comment: @Muhammad see other answer, second option. That is what I normally do.

Comment: I am trying that but no luck yet, the query is quite complex, let me post the whole query, in the question.

Comment: I have updated the question, I have posted the whole query now.